# Why some field from content type never show?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I create a document list called Publication groups, whose default content type is Publication. In the content type publication, there are some fields such as item no, kit number and so on.[image]

But I can never see the project field in the browser. I never set it to hidden. What may possible lead to this? Thank you very much.

PS: I am going to Column Order page, trying to set visibility of some column.
[image]

Eidt:

I used CSOM code to check the hidden property of this field in Visual Studio. The hidden property is false. So it is not set to be hidden. But it doesn't show in the page. What could be wrong??? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Check the values of SPField.ShowInNewForm, ShowInDisplayForm and ShowInEditForm. You can do that with PowerShell.

Comment: @Naim, Hi, Is it possible to do that with web UI or with sharepoint designer?

Comment: No. Why don't you check with PowerShell?

Comment: @Naim. I am very new to sharepoint. I don't know how to do that. Could you give me some documents about that? Or give me some tutor? Thanks very much.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the values of SPField.ShowInNewForm, ShowInDisplayForm and ShowInEditForm. You can do that with PowerShell.

Open SharePoint Management Shell and run the following script

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YourSiteUrl
$list = $web.Lists["YourListName"]
$field = $list.Fields["YourFieldName"]
$field.ShowInNewForm
```

If ShowInNewForm is False you can set it to True

```
$field.ShowInNewForm = $true
$field.Update()
```

Do the same for ShowInDisplayForm and ShowInEditForm.

Comment: Hi Naim. Forgive me as a new  bird in sharepoint. Something is wrong with Sharepoint Online Management Shell. Could you please help check? The new post is here. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150699/sharepoint-online-power-shell-never-work/150738#150738

Comment: Hi Naim. I used CSOM code to check the hidden property of Project field. It is false. So this field is not set to be hidden. But It just doesn't show in the page. What could be wrong??? See my edit.

Comment: A field can have Hidden=False but if ShowInDisplayForm is False then it will not be shown in the display form (same goes for ShowInEditForm and ShowInNewForm). With CSOM you can use SetShowInDisplayForm(true). Are you checking the field taken from the list's field collection or content type's field collection. Check both.

Comment: Hi, I find the point. Sure, you are right. I modified the ShowInEditForm to be ture, and it shows! By the way,I am just wondering when someone creates a filed in the WebUI, is it possible from him to modify it in UI? Otherwise, he has to use PowerShell or CSOM to modify it?

Comment: It can't be changed with the UI. The default value for ShowInDisplayForm, ShowInEditForm and ShowInNewForm is true unless its a column deployed with custom SP solution where (intentionally, by design) the content type schema has False value for ShowInDisplayForm etc.

Comment: Mark the answer as solved if this resolved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make the column visible from the content type setting. For that you'll need to goto list setting, click on the content type and there you can set the order of the columns and also which fields are visible on dispaly, edit and new forms. Do let me know if you need a complete tutorial.

Comment: See my edit. I am in the column order page. How can I set the visibility? Thanks.

Comment: click on the field on the previous page. and see if it's hidden!

Comment: hi, this is what I am wondering. I see it is set as required, not hidden. But it never show in the web page. So this is why I am asking.