# SharePoint online power shell commands are not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I installed Sharepoint online management shell in my local computer, and I want to connect to the remote sharepoint server. But when I type the command, it is wrong.

[image]

I searched in some methods, one is to invoke this: 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

But I checked, there is no such dll in my gac. Shall I need to install something? Thank you very much.

Edit:
I also tried this command, but it failed, either.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact solution for your problem is that you need to **import the sharepoint commands after installation.**

Then type the required commands to connect to the online service. You also need to be tenant admin for your office 365 environment.

Pls refer the picture below with exact details.

[image]

Comment: Hi, the issue is fixed according to your method. THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint Online Management Shell has less amount of commands than it's version for on-premise. You can read all possible commands there:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161397.aspx
If you want to connect to service, you have to start from this command:
Connect-SPOService
But you have to be a global administrator in Office 365
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-the-SharePoint-Online-Management-Shell-c16941c3-19b4-4710-8056-34c034493429

If you want to get Web, I suggest you to use CSOM from powershell. Client Object Model gives you more wide functional for managing your sites.

Comment: Hi, I tried Connect-SPOService, but it also failed. Could you help check? Thanks.

Comment: its not a relevant answer. for this problem he needs to import the commands first as i mentioned in the below answer.

Comment: The user is really asking why it's not working to connect to Offce 365. Sending links is not the answer to the question. You need to revise the answer and explain how to connect, and not give a general answer on what commands are available. Down vote from me.